# Exibir texto ao pé do ponteiro do mouse ao descansá-lo em uma imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou pesquisando desde ontem como exibir um texto ao descansar o ponteiro do mouse em uma imagem e ver informação (como um `title`, mas onde eu possa editar a cor da fonte, background e etc) e com a ajuda de um amigo esse foi o mais perto que eu cheguei:

[image: O que acontece quando descanso o mouse em cima de uma imagem]

Não dá pra ver o ponteiro do mouse porque é um print, mas o mouse esta em cima da bolsa vermelha, o item do lado superior direito da tela, do lado das espadinhas vermelhas.

O problema é que em vez do texto aparecer ao pé do ponteiro do mouse (assim como num `title`) ele sempre aparece naquele canto superior esquerdo. Eu queria deixar assim:

[image: Tooltip posicionada corretamente abaixo do ponteiro do mouse]

Também, diferentemente do `title` eu quero que a mensagem apareça instantaneamente ao descansar o mouse, ao invés de aparecer com delay. Aqui o link de uma pagina onde se pode ver um modelo [funcionando perfeitamente](https://marlborowars.net/?subtopic=characters&name=%5BDNT%5D%20Mister%20May)

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: help;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(100% + 2px);
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #000;
  color: Yellow;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-tooltip="Unclear Backpack"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" ></span>
</div>
```

css da classe da img, que define a posição onde cada imagem vai aparecer

```
#piv_flex .itm { background-image: url("/engine/img/bg.png"); }
#piv_flex .itm-1  { left: 48px; top: 39px; }
#piv_flex .itm-2  { left: 11px; top: 53px; }
#piv_flex .itm-3  { left: 85px; top: 53px; }
#piv_flex .itm-4  { left: 48px; top: 76px; }
#piv_flex .itm-5  { left: 85px; top: 90px; }
#piv_flex .itm-6  { left: 11px; top: 90px; }
#piv_flex .itm-7  { left: 48px; top: 113px; }
#piv_flex .itm-8  { left: 48px; top: 150px; }
#piv_flex .itm-9  { left: 11px; top: 127px; }
#piv_flex .itm-10 { left: 85px; top: 127px; }
```

Comment: Simplifiquei o código porque não há necessidade de inserir PHP nessa sua pergunta. Removi a classe da tag `<img>` pois você não colocou o CSS dela. Se for importante, edite a pergunta acrescentando novamente a classe e o CSS correspondente

Comment: Cara no. final das contas não ficou muito claro o que vc quer... o tooltip já está aparecendo no seu exemplo de código... Vc quer que o tooltip siga o ponteiro do mouse? Ou que o tooltip aparece centralizado logo abaixo da imagem?

Comment: Acessando a pagina que eu linkei no tópico da ver melhor se você estiver em um desktop/notebook, mas basicamente quero que o tooltip fique abaixo do ponteiro do mouse, exatamente como ficaria em um `title`, não precisa seguir o mouse. Centralizado abaixo da imagem também resolveria

Answer (score -1):

O que você quer se chama Tooltip. Aconselho usar o Bootstrap para fazer com mais facilidade. Fiz de forma bem simples e fácil entendimento, depois é só você arrumar o que quiser.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #343434;
  color: #f6f604;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 65%;
  left: 175%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <img class="" src="http://items.znote.eu/12520.gif">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Hearth Backpack</span>
</div>
```

Comment: então, a box com as informações continua aparecendo no lado superior esquerdo... sera que é algum conflito com o meu css? sempre chego nesse exato problema com todo código que eu tento

Comment: Use o código da forma que eu lhe enviei. Se continuar o erro, deve ser algum conflito no CSS entre as `class`. Use o inspecionar elemento na `<div>` e dá uma olhada, veja se acha alguma coisa.

Comment: inspecionando: https://pastebin.com/yAHeaNx4

Comment: Você tem uma class igual a `.tooltip`? O que há de CSS nas class da `<img>`?

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta em relação ao HTML e CSS. Execute o código aqui pelo stack e veja se está certo.

Comment: Não tenho nenhuma outra class igual a `.tooltip`, e a class da img vou adicionar no post principal. Com seu novo código continuei na mesma, mas agr to começando a acha que é conflito com p css da img..

Comment: Estranho. Consegue me enviar um fiddle contendo o código completo?

Comment: Tente remover as classes da imagem. O código está com a imagem que mostrou no pastebin e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Tirei todas as classes das imagens mas continuou na mesma... n consegui fazer o fiddle pq o código usa consultas + arquivos locais. Sera que java script faria isso mais facil?

Comment: Acho que não. Só o CSS já consegue suprir toda essa necessidade. Mas se for o caso, use Bootstrap, pois o Tooltip já vem pronto. Aqui o link da documentação do Tooltip: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/